# How to get future date based on another date in android?

Tags: android, calendar

I want to choose date by date picker dialog and based on that I need to get a date after 20days. For eg: If I choose 2-5-2021, need to get 22-5-2021.But I got parseException. How to achieve this?

My code is,

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = null;
try {
  date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(transactionDate.getText().toString());
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
  calendar.setTime(date);
  calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);
  Toast.makeText(this, (CharSequence) calendar.getTime(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: check the text you get from `transactionDate.getText()` . It must be in wrong format

Comment: I got the text as 12-5-2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for this:

```
public void getCalculatedDate() {
    try {
        String date = selectedDate.getText().toString();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date parseDate = format.parse(date);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(parseDate);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);
        newDate.setText(format.format(cal.getTime()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Note:**  selectedDate which is got from date picker dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function and pass the parameters as your present date and the no of days you want to add(20).

```
public static String getCalculatedDate(String dateFormat, int days) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, days);
        return s.format(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
    }
```

Comment: This method will calculate the future date by current date right.

Comment: Yes.  Please accept the answer if you get it working

Comment: This is not am expected anyhow it's working so am going to recommend it.